# JMeter Grape config for groovy on Windows?

Tags: windows, groovy, jmeter, groovy-grape

Currently I'm trying to run groovy scripts in JMeter with grape in windows:
My JMeter has c:\JMeter\lib\groovy-all.2.4.16.jar, c:\JMeter\lib\ivy-2.5.0.jar (heard needed this).

A lot of examples I see for grape config are in Linux.  I put the grapeConfig.xml in c:\JMeter\ with the following settings:

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="downloadGrapes"/>
  <resolvers>
    <chain name="downloadGrapes">
      <filesystem name="cachedGrapes">
        <ivy pattern="${user.home}/.groovy/grapes/[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml"/>
        <artifact pattern="${user.home}/.groovy/grapes/[organisation]/[module]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
      </filesystem>
      <!-- todo add 'endorsed groovy extensions' resolver here -->
      <ibiblio name="codehaus" root="http://repository.codehaus.org/" m2compatible="true"/>
      <ibiblio name="ibiblio" m2compatible="true"/>
      <ibiblio name="java.net2" root="http://download.java.net/maven/2/" m2compatible="true"/>
      <!-- this fixes the missing 2.1_3 version of cglib-nodep -->
      <ibiblio name="mirror" root="http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/" m2compatible="true"/>
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

When I execute a script in JMeter I get the following error as part of a groovy @Grab:

```
General error during conversion: Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1!commons-logging.jar]

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1!commons-logging.jar]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated on getting proper configuration of grape with JMeter and groovy on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Global grapeConfig.xml](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Global-grapeConfig-xml-td391461.html) thread Grape is checking the following:

- `grape.config` [system property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) (if it is not null)
- `groovy.root` system property (if it is not null)
- `user.home/.groovy` folder

So in order to "tell" JMeter to use your custom `grapeConfig.xml` you need to launch JMeter like:

```
jmeter -Dgrape.config=c:/JMeter/grapeConfig.xml -t your_script.jmx
```

To make the change permanent add the next line to `system.properties` file:

```
grape.config=c:/JMeter/grapeConfig.xml
```

More information:

- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  One thing... I had to remove my c:\Users\username\.groovy directory at one point.  After loading again I got all the required jars.c:\Users\username\.groovy\grapes directory